# Money Data Type Precision - SQL Server (SSMS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, currency

In sql server management studio, data type- money, when I enter an amount with a decimal it automatically adds on zeros to fill up to the hundredths. How can I determine the amount of spaces after the decimal?

Comment: What are you asking? How to not display trailing zeroes or how to accommodate a greater number of decimal places?

Answer (score 6):

The number of zeroes behind the dot is called the `precision` of a datatype.  The `money` data type has a [fixed precision](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258271(SQL.80).aspx):

```
with accuracy to a ten-thousandth of a monetary unit.
```

That's five digits behind the dot.  If you'd like a different precision, use the `decimal` datatype.  Some examples:

```
select  cast(0.123456789 as money)
,       cast(0.123456789 as decimal(5,3))
,       cast(0.123456789 as decimal(5,1))
```

This prints:

```
0.1235    0.123    0.1
```

Comment: Try using 0.1000 and see what your output is...  for me, it's '0.10' (missing the 3rd and 4th 0's after the decimal).

Comment: I believe that the precision is the total number of digits in the number, and the scale is how many of those are to the right of the decimal point.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258274%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Andomar As demonstrated by your examples, ten-thousandths is *four* (not five) digits after the dot (tenths, hundredths, thousandths, ten-thousandths)

Comment: Precision is the number of digits in a number. Scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point in a number. For example, the number 123.45 has a precision of 5 and a scale of 2.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15