# Adding data to money type column ignores '.'

Tags: sql-server

I'm having problems adding data to a column in my sql management studio

I'm trying to add : `138.00`

but sql management studio always changes it to : `13800,0000`

Why does this keep happening, no matter if I put `float` or `decimal` it always replaces the `.` with `blank`

Comment: sql managment studio 2014 @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Refer this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes_general.asp

Comment: it doesn't matter if i choose float or decimal types it stills remove the '.' and put the number together with the decimals @PiyushGupta

Comment: what means ' change it ' ? It looks like a [regionals settings](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/458416/microsoft-sql-server-management-studio-doesnt-get-os-regional-setting) issue.

Comment: have you tried with money data type?

Comment: You can use FLOAT(5,2) where 5 is total digit and 2 is decimal value......I tested this in MySQL workbench and inserted 138.00 its working......and Money data type is not supported to oracle and MySQL.......Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914868/money-data-type-precision-sql-server-ssms